# SVNServer moved to other server, cant relocate project

Tags: windows, visualsvn-server, tortoisesvn

I just moved my repositories to another server by copying the pasting the files in the appropriate folder. In the new server I can see the repositories loaded correctly. But when I go to my visual studio projects folders and right click TortoiseSVN -> relocate 
From url: `http://xx.xx.x.101:81/svn/Proj` to Url: `http://xx.xx.x.1:81/svn/Proj` but it throws time out. Any suggestions how to fix it?

**EDIT**

I opened the 81 port in firewall with no luck...

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State


TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [VisualSVNServer.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I changed my url to `http://xx.xx.x.1:445/svn/Proj` but now I got this error: error running context an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Hire *real admin*, dude! `http xx.xx.x.1:445``is **SUPERMEGAUBERLOL!!!**

Comment: Port 445/TCP is used by SMB/CIFS for Windows file sharing. It is not a good idea to use it for other things.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a RHEL based distribution like CentOS. Let me know if you have something else.

Timeout usually means that there is a firewall or a routing problem. If ping works, then it is firewall. I will list below some generic things to check.

Make sure that you have apache configured with mod_dav.

```
apachectl -M
```

Make sure apache is listening on port 81 on the ethernet interface or on all interfaces.

```
sudo netstat -anp|grep :81
```

Make sure port 81 is open in firewall and that is labeled properly in SELinux.

```
sudo semanage port -l|grep 81
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 81  # To add it if it is missing
```

Make sure the port is open in local firewall or any firewall on the path. Check also the firewall on your desktop machine.

```
iptables -l   # To list the rules on the local firewall.
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that both servers are windows

Comment: Run `netstat -ban > netstat-ban.txt`, then run `notepad netstat-ban.txt`. This will show what applications are running on which port. Make sure web server is listening on port 81. Which web server are you running by the way?

Comment: please see my post for info